# Mutating type based on methods called

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a class that should allow you to parse a `Buffer` with chaining

```js
class Parser<T> {
  private buffer: Buffer;
  private offset: number;
  private varsInternal: Record<>;

  constructor(buffer: Buffer) {
    this.offset = 0;
    this.buffer = buffer;
    this.varsInternal = {};
  }

  char(name: string): this {
    const val = this.buffer.readUInt8(this.offset);
    this.varsInternal[name] = val;
    this.offset += 1;
    return this;
  }

  short(name: string): this {
    const val = this.buffer.readUInt16BE(this.offset);
    this.varsInternal[name] = val;
    this.offset += 2;
    return this;
  }

 vars(): T {
    return this.varsInternal;
  }
}
```

So what you could do is this:

```js
const data = new Parser(myBuffer)
  .char("myChar")
  .char("otherChar")
  .short("myShort")
  .vars();

console.log(data); // { myChar: 32, otherChar: 123, myShort: 123544 }
```

But I have to manually write types for this:

```js
const data = new Parser(myBuffer)
  .char("myChar")
  .char("otherChar")
  .short("myShort")
  .vars();

console.log(data.myChar);
              // ^^^^^^ does not exist

const data2 = new Parser<{ myChar: number, otherChar: number, myShort: number }>(myBuffer)
  .char("myChar")
  .char("otherChar")
  .short("myShort")
  .vars();

console.log(data.myChar); // works
```

You can see that this gets ugly.

So I am wondering if it is possible to write the return values of `char` and `short` in a way that tells TypeScript that `vars` will add a field every time I am chaining with `char` and `short`

Comment: sorry, I deleted my comment because I can see `number` in your example code

Answer (score 1):

A possible idea is to extend your returned `Parser<T>` type every time you add a new property. In this case `T` is the type representing your whole `Record` data structure.

```
class Parser<T extends Record<string, number> = Record<string, number>> {
    private buffer: Buffer;
    private offset: number;
    private varsInternal: T

    constructor(buffer: Buffer) {
        this.offset = 0;
        this.buffer = buffer;
        this.varsInternal = {} as T;
    }

    char<K extends string>(name: K): Parser<T & Record<K, number>> {
        const val = this.buffer.readUInt8(this.offset); // returns number
        this.varsInternal[name] = val;
        this.offset += 1;
        return this as Parser<T & Record<K, number>>
    }

    // change short method analogue to char above

    vars() {
        return this.varsInternal;
    }
}
```

For example invoking `myParser.char("myChar")` will return `Parser<T & Record<"myChar", number>>` - the previous data record `T` is extended or intersected with a `Record` containing the new added key `K`, which is `"myChar"` here.

Some testing proves, that we now have a strong type:

```
const data = new Parser({/* buffer */ })
    .char("myChar")
    .char("otherChar")
    .vars();

data.otherChar // works, number
data.myChar // works, number
```

[Code sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgrgMwRATlAvFAhgOxFAegCoocB7AE2gHMAbMgIy1qiIICh2BjWrAZz5QAClhR9UAHgAqUCAA9gEHBUEAlCFzIoKEvsBQBLHNQA0pOAFsGqAHwYo6zdt36jp81dt2A3uyj+oMEMANyxFKAZEZBQALlgo1ABuPwCgg1DwsiRxYDicS2sUZIDAkLDoULEASRxFFBxmOKlOEs0cPRQ4LmAtAApIpFQ4+EGUAEooXxKS4AALAz4AOiyEHPsABmLp-zmFxYHo+wOklO3dpcq+GrqGlkxvAF9sQSkt-weWgK5Z0QkAaVkCiUKigHTcNl6DQsEDifzGcREYkkMgAZA4NFodH8zPlPCgbD5TtM2nooKE7lBzvsEihFigIFgKABVa4ADl6VJWOTGiUIBCg9OAcHqglxhSJM3mF1EV1qqFuAG0oRAALr2clvaac7IQYBQADUmAAjJqSoLhThKVLnsIZcioGjHJj-jiCl4iR8iQR+d9cNRoHxZlo9dC5pRsLcyNQ4NAelBfWgsAwyMEIJ9-JdehMptsBbqLVa9pdrvLmJqPp6SXqKGEsPYcBAAO62pEoXreYgRGmsfkPMZExYJ3oAIgsIAAwj8UMP+yVB1OR2Q5qhJ6IZwPMzzODXgFhlsuUKu0N6oI2tABrPiuvHsHd7sdHvmni9Xjzi9hAA)

Comment: Since the return types are known for the methods, instead of using `any` using `Record<K, string>` would be nicer other than that it's a neat solution.

Comment: @Eldar good catch, seems that OP expects `number` here as Record value type (updated answer).

Comment: For `char` method it should be  `string` and for short method it should be `number` etc.

Comment: yeah, depends on how it will be processed further. For the scope of this parser class, `number` seems to be sufficient, as all example values and types use it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's come up with a type alias `AddProp<T, K, V>` which takes an object type `T`, a key type `K`, and a value type `V`, and produces a new object type with all the properties from `T` as well as a new property with key `K` and value `V`.  Here's one way to define it:

```
type AddProp<T, K extends PropertyKey, V> =
    (T & { [P in K]: V }) extends infer O ? { [P in keyof O]: O[P] } : never;
```

The type `(T & {[P in K]: V})` by itself would do the job, but at the end of your chaining call you'd get an ugly type like `AddProp<AddProp<{myChar: number;}, "otherChar", number>, "myShort", number>`, so I'm using a trick with a [conditional type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) that expands out the properties into a single object type like `{myChar: number; otherChar: number; myShort: number}`.

---

Armed with that, let's start redefining `Parser`'s types:

```
class Parser<T = {}> {
    private buffer: Buffer;
    private offset: number;
    private varsInternal: T;

    constructor(buffer: Buffer) {
        this.offset = 0;
        this.buffer = buffer;
        this.varsInternal = {} as T;
    }
```

Here I've set a [default](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) value of `T` to be the empty object type `{}`.  And we want `varsInternal` to be of type `T`, and we have to [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) that the initial value `{}` for `varsInternal` matches the `T` (which it won't if you manually specify `T` as in `new Parser<{a: number}>(buffer)`... so don't do that).

Now let's add a private method to reuse that will add a property with key of type `K` and value of type `V`  to `this.varsInternal` and return `this`, where we assert that the returned `this` will be of type `Parser<AddProp<T, K, V>>`.  The idea here is that this will take care of the type mutation in your other methods:

```
    private addProp<K extends PropertyKey, V>(prop: K, val: V): Parser<AddProp<T, K, V>> {
        (this.varsInternal as any)[prop] = val;
        return this as any;
    }
```

And here are your `char()` and `short()` methods.  Note that these need to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) in the `name` property, since `string` is too wide to keep track of the particular keys added to `T`.

```
    char<K extends PropertyKey>(name: K) {
        const val = this.buffer.readUInt8(this.offset);
        const ret = this.addProp(name, val);
        this.offset += 1;
        return ret;
    }

    short<K extends PropertyKey>(name: K) {
        const val = this.buffer.readUInt16BE(this.offset);
        const ret = this.addProp(name, val);
        this.offset += 2;
        return ret;
    }
```

And your `vars()` is the same:

```
    vars(): T {
        return this.varsInternal;
    }
}
```

Let's test it out:

```
declare const myBuffer: Buffer;

const data = new Parser(myBuffer)
    .char("myChar")
    .char("otherChar")
    .short("myShort")
    .vars();
/* const data: {
    myChar: number;
    otherChar: number;
    myShort: number;
}*/

console.log(data.myChar); // number
```

Looks good.  The retured type of `data` is `{myChar: number, otherChar: number, myShort: number}`.  If those values should be of a different type, you should process `val` inside `char()` and/or `short()` before calling `this.addProp()`.

Anyway, I'll stop there; hope this helps.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAIQK4DMUFMpxVCI4DkAdhACboECwAUDTAJ5jpwCCppACrmADwAqAGjgBpOOgAeMdEVIBnOFwhNY9YenpCAagD44AXhpwjcABR84AMjgBvOAG0OcYEREBdAFxxNcAL4BKMUlpOSciDCwAeTgAfht7R2c4AGt1CBQ4CI8Mh1dfOE8idAA3TABuGhoAYwAbAENZeQ5aqFlMfn0bH11rQ2MwKGAi2qk4ACNUcM9kNDLeo37B4eY0lFaYAqQQUdnqYzgFoZGhloBJIikoIlrqzz5y2l3jSogiWRgoJEqYaBNxmagphNMAEeo89kYYAALYCyAB0KzWHQADPdwcYoTDYX9wh1sTs0RDoXDjrIzhcrtUOtYfHB6nA7nNfBUwfsBodmLV2IpeKIJFIZI1uJgGGoNF5tCZ+kpPMIhEMbl4-J4mi02mxONx+EJZeLuoy9iYMcTmqTzpgKbT5LUiPQ-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)